# Show data based on echart's pie slice click using Angular

Tags: angular, echarts

I just want to show the data of echarts(pie chart) in the table when i click on the pie slice i want to show that corresponding data only in the table (on pie slice click). So i am trying this since so many days but no clue i got. So can anyone suggest how it can be achieved? I mean the data w.r.t that particular pie slice only. Means on clicking the pie slice the that clicked data should be reflected on the table? Please help me on this. For reference please check the image attached.
[image]

```
const tempArray = this.categoryCount.map(x => ({
        value: x.count,
        name: x.groupBy
      }));
      this.ccArray2 = tempArray;
// Pie chart
      this.PlaybookChart3 = {
        title: {
          text: "Category Breakdown",
          x: "left"
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: "item",
          formatter: "{c}",
          textStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 13
          }
        },
        // Enable drag recalculate
        calculable: true,
        series: [
          {
            type: "pie",
            radius: "75%",
            center: ["50%", "50%"],
            selectedMode: "single",
            data: this.ccArray2,
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true,
                position: "outside"
              },
              emphasis: {
                show: true,
                textStyle: {
                  fontSize: "13"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      };
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div *ngIf="PlaybookChart3 != undefined" class="col-xl-6 mat-elevation-z8 pt-3 mx-auto" myECharts
            [EChartsOptions]="PlaybookChart3" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

Thanks.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-rich-text

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a sample Stackblitz to work with? If you do, please share it across so that we could have a look.

Comment: No i dont have any code.

Comment: Would you mind creating one so that someone out here could have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can drill down to each sector in a `pie(echart)`,Use

```
 PlaybookChart3.on('click',
     function(params) {
             //your code
     });
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _this.PlaybookChart3.on is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (tt.component.ts:414)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
   ... got this error..